# Limitar tags no bootstrap-tagsinput v0.8.0

Tags: jquery

Estou precisando criar um campo onde se possa colocar  um determinado numero de tags em um input do formulário.

Estou usando o plugin **bootstrap-tagsinput v0.8.0** do jquery, consegui fazer funcionar, mais ele não limita a quantidade de palavras a serem digitadas, teria como fazer isso nesse plugin **bootstrap-tagsinput v0.8.0**?

Dessa forma faz a limitação igual nos dois. Mas como faço para que quando eu tiver dois inputs, limita 3 para um e 10 para o outro?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('input').tagsinput({
  maxTags: 3
});
```

Html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="card-box">
      <h4 class="header-title m-t-0 m-b-20">Palavras-chave</h4>
      <p class="text-muted font-14">
         Permitido até 40 palavras
      </p>
      <div class="tags-default">
         <input type="text" id="palavras_chave" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="card-box">
      <h4 class="header-title m-t-0 m-b-20">Marcas</h4>
      <p class="text-muted font-14">
         Permitido até 50 palavras
      </p>
      <div class="tags-default">
         <input type="text" id="marcas"  data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara da uma lida na documentação do plugin.

Comment: onde consigo a documentação?

Comment: https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput

Comment: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: ali fala para fazer assim $('input').tagsinput({
  maxTags: 3
});  Dessa forma faz a limitação igual nos dois. Mas como faço para que quando eu tiver dois inputs, limita 3 para um e 10 para o outro?

Comment: Se vc colocar aqui o código que já desenvolveu fica mais fácil de obter ajuda no site.

Comment: editei minha resposta com o que você pediu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O exemplo funcionando

```js
$('#palavras_chave').tagsinput({
   maxTags: 3
})

$('#marcas').tagsinput({
   maxTags: 4
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="card-box">
      <h4 class="header-title m-t-0 m-b-20">Palavras-chave</h4>
      <p class="text-muted font-14">
         Permitido até 40 palavras
      </p>
      <div class="tags-default">
         <input type="text" id="palavras_chave" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="card-box">
      <h4 class="header-title m-t-0 m-b-20">Marcas</h4>
      <p class="text-muted font-14">
         Permitido até 50 palavras
      </p>
      <div class="tags-default">
         <input type="text" id="marcas"  data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: não funcionou para mim, tem algum exemplo?

Comment: daria para colocar um class no input e chamar no juqery?

Comment: tentei assim 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.palavras_chave').tagsinput({  // pega o primeiro input
       maxTags: 3
    });
   
}); mas nao deu certo

Comment: Não vai dar certo mesmo do jeito que vc colocou. No seu **HTML** vc está colocando o palavras_chaves como **id** e asim tem que chamar no jQuery com **#** e não **.** como vc fez. Tem que ser **$('#palavras_chave')** para funcionar.

Comment: coloquei o $('#palavras_chave')  e também nao deu certo, teria algum exemplo funcionando?

Comment: Ta funcionando blza.

Comment: Se foi útil a resposta marque-a como respondida para fechá-la.